# C++ how do you add environment variables in the code?

Tags: c++, variables, environment

I would like to add a environment variable in the code and give it a value
how can I do such a thing
Could you guys give me an example

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `putenv` for this.

http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/putenv.html

If you're on windows, you can use [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

have a look at `getenv()` and `setenv()` ; for ex like this:

```
char *shell;


/* Get the path of the current shell to start it later */
shell = getenv("SHELL");
if (shell == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error eding SHELL env. var.\n");
    return 1;
}       

/* Overwrite env. var. PATH */
if (setenv("PATH", "/usr/bin", 1) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting env. var.\n");
    return 1;
}
```